# What is the most robust web frontend for MPD for Linaro/Ubuntu 14.xx?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, streaming, mpd, linaro

I've built a headless server instance with linaro on a Radxa rock connected to speakers, and am currently trying out rompr.

Does MPD offer any other "streaming" jukebox style frontend options for having one's music streams or at least directories, all in one place/interface?

I am most interested in shoutcast/icecast streams, with the ability to add streams by URL as needed if the don't appear on popular directories. UPnP detection of my local music on my LAN would be a bonus, but not essential.